# cakephp 2.X override table prefix dynamically on join action

Tags: sql, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I a cakephp setup to manage multiple web-sites in which they a number of common models, with the table prefix 'main_'. And there's common model Fbuser is using a table 'main_fb_users'

And now, I have a web-site, and its table prefix is 'myweb_', and I have a model, Mymodel, which have to be left-join with  Fbuser.

```
$this->Mymodel->find('all', array(
'joins' => array(
'table' => 'main_fb_users',
'alias' => 'Fbuser',
'type' => 'LEFT',
'conditions' => array('Mymodel.field01 = Fbuser.field02')
));
```

and here's the error message I have got

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbserver.myweb_main_fb_users' doesn't exist
```

obviously, it's due to the different in the table prefix, and I can't change the default table prefix set in the database.php.

so how can I override the table prefix inside the join query?

Comment: what happens when you set table to "dbserver.main_fb_users" explicitly?

Comment: coz' the tables 'dbserver.main_fb_users' and 'dbserver.myweb_mymodels' are having different table prefix, 'main_' and 'myweb_' respectively.

and the table prefix is set at the database.php... and so the join action automatically add 'myweb_' to 'main_fb_users', and which is the cause the my problem

Comment: You didn't accept any solution nor did you post an update!! Did anything below work for you or you used a custom setup?

Answer (score 3):

Pass the model object instead of the table name as a string:

```
$this->Mymodel->find('all', array(
'joins' => array(
'table' => $this->Mymodel->FbUser,
'alias' => 'Fbuser',
'type' => 'LEFT',
'conditions' => array('Mymodel.field01 = Fbuser.field02')
));
```

Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hacked Method** (for version 2.x)

Go to - /lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php  line #942

Modify the function fullTableName as below:

```
    public function fullTableName($model, $quote = true, $schema = true, $prefix = true) {
            if (is_object($model)) {
                $schemaName = $model->schemaName;
                $table = $model->tablePrefix . $model->table;
            } elseif (!empty($this->config['prefix']) && strpos($model, $this->config['prefix']) !== 0) {
                $table = (((!empty($prefix) && $prefix !== true)?$prefix:(($prefix === false)?'':$this->config['prefix'] ))). strval($model);
            } else {
                $table = strval($model);
            }

            if ($schema && !isset($schemaName)) {
                $schemaName = $this->getSchemaName();
            }

            if ($quote) {
                if ($schema && !empty($schemaName)) {
                    if (strstr($table, '.') === false) {
                        return $this->name($schemaName) . '.' . $this->name($table);
                    }
                }
                return $this->name($table);
            }

            if ($schema && !empty($schemaName)) {
                if (strstr($table, '.') === false) {
                    return $schemaName . '.' . $table;
                }
            }

            return $table;
        }
```

Now go to line #1881 on same page and modify the function buildJoinStatement as:

```
    public function buildJoinStatement($join) {
            $data = array_merge(array(
                'type' => null,
                'alias' => null,
                'table' => 'join_table',
                'conditions' => '',
            ), $join);

            if (!empty($data['alias'])) {
                $data['alias'] = $this->alias . $this->name($data['alias']);
            }
            if (!empty($data['conditions'])) {
                $data['conditions'] = trim($this->conditions($data['conditions'], true, false));
            }
            if (!empty($data['table']) && (!is_string($data['table']) || strpos($data['table'], '(') !== 0)) {
                $data['table'] = (isset($data['prefix']))?$this->fullTableName($data['table'],true,true,$data['prefix']):$this->fullTableName($data['table']);
            }
            return $this->renderJoinStatement($data);
        }
```

thats it...

now if you provide a prefix element in joins array then it will use the same prefix for that table.

**Example**

```
    'joins'=>array(
        array(
            'table'=>'GDN_Comment',
            'type'=>'LEFT',
            'prefix'=>false,
            'alias'=>'Comment',
            'conditions'=>array('MyPost.DiscussionID = 2'),
        ),
    ),
```

Then it will use "GDN_Comment as Comment" in sql query

**OR**

```
    'joins'=>array(
        array(
            'table'=>'GDN_Comment',
            'type'=>'LEFT',
            'prefix'=>'ds_',
            'alias'=>'Comment',
            'conditions'=>array('MyPost.DiscussionID = 2'),
        ),
    ),
```

Then it will use "ds_GDN_Comment as Comment" in sql query

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the table prefix on the fly in the controller:

```
$this->loadModel('MainFbUser');
$this->MainFbUser->tablePrefix = '';
```

In the documentation:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#tableprefix